# Changing class of element in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, web, vs-web-site-project

Hello like in the subject,
I want to change the class of the item like this:

```
<a class="nav-link active" href="#"> --> <a class="nav-link" href="#">
```

Have you any ideas? Thanks for ur answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ngClass directive:

```
<a class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'active' : condition}" href="#">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [class.] directive provided by angular like so:

```html
<a class="nav-link" [class.active]"your-condition" href="#">
```

You can read more about this here: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#binding-to-the-class-attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using a condition to decide the classes you are going to apply to the element. You may use `ngClass` directive to decide the classes to apply:

```
<a [ngClass]="{'nav-link active' : condition1, 'nav-link': condition2}" href="#">
Click here
</a>
```

The above is an example only. You may use this example to write to evaluate different expressions/conditions and apply one or more CSS classes.